# Is disposing a panel equivalent to disposing its children plus itself?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, dispose

Within the following class:

```
class MyPanel : Panel
{
    ...
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // My code here
    }
}
```

are the following two code samples equivalent?

```
base.Dispose(disposing);
```

vs

```
if (disposing)
{
    List<Control> ctrls = new List<Control>(this.Controls);
    this.Controls.Clear();  
    foreach(Control c in ctrls)
    {
         c.Dispose();
    }
}
base.Dispose(disposing);
```

If they have a different effect, what would it be?

**Edit:** I ask this because, for whatever reason, doing it the first way freezes my program before it gets to disposing any of its children (`disposing` is true, and `Controls` contains 2 controls), whereas the second way works fine. If I can happily use the second one, then that's great.

Comment: It is logically the same with, normally, the same outcome.  The Clear() call moves the control windows to the parking window.  This (threading) bug is going to byte your rear end another way some day.

Comment: @Joe: I'm pretty sure we're talking about the same thing. If the children panels are still running and generating events, it's clear that you're leaking event handlers. That doesn't mean the second method is better, it means you need to manage your objects properly.

Comment: @Cody, you are right. i just realised as i was looking through the code that what i was doing was iterating through my presenters (per view) and disposing of them, thus disposing of the event handlers. i do not dispose of every button and textbox on the view, that would be silly, hence retracting my first comment. btw, i'm not the same joe that commented on your answer, that's an imposter!

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, disposing the container will automatically dispose of its child controls.**

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4zkb31d.aspx), the `Control.Dispose` method:

> Releases the unmanaged resources used by the Control **and its child controls** and optionally releases the managed resources.

So calling the `Dispose` method on the `Panel` control will automatically dispose its child controls. However, there is an important caveat to this, as noted by Joe's comment: the child controls must have unsubscribed from events that are declared outside of the parent's scope. If the events are members of objects that will stay alive, they will keep the child controls alive as well and prevent them from being properly disposed. Obviously you don't need to unsubscribe from events declared in objects that are being disposed of simultaneously, such as the parent.

Of course, it's also worth nothing that this can be extended to the `Panel` control's container (most likely a `Form` control). Whenever you `Dispose` the `Form` that owns the `Panel`, both the `Panel` control and all of its children will be disposed for you automatically. There's no reason to do so explicitly for the `Panel` control, unless you're adding and removing instances to and from your form dynamically.

Comment: That's interesting. What do you mean by "owns the Panel" because what i do is create a control and then add it to the form. And with this method, if i were to dispose the form, the timers on the controls that were added will keep firing. I'm guessing the key here is ownership, how do you get the parent to own a child that's not declared from within the designer.cs file of the form.

Comment: @Joe: You've thrown a wrench into things when you said "timers". How did you add the timers to the controls? There's no guarantee that the timers will be disposed when the controls themselves are, because they're not necessarily *owned* by the control.

Comment: hum... my timers are created from the constructor within the control that's added to the form. so there shouldn't be scoping issues there...

Comment: @Cody - Do you know if it'll do anything *extra* in that first example?

Comment: @Smashery: I'm not sure that I know what you mean. What first example? What sort of extra things? There's nothing magical that goes on.

Comment: The first example as in the first of those two code samples I presented: `base.Dispose(disposing)`. My question is slightly elaborated in the edit, and I just want to make sure I'm not missing anything by using the second code sample.

Comment: @Smashery: My suggestion is to figure out why the first method is freezing/crashing your program. Regardless of potential workarounds, that indicates a potentially serious issue. I don't recommend just ignoring it. Step through the code with a debugger, see where it goes and what it does.

Comment: The best that the debugger has shown is that it gets to `base.Dispose(true)` and freezes before it calls `Dispose` on any of its child items (breakpoints in these turn up nothing). This is the exact reason I am asking the question: if it does something else, perhaps I can stick a breakpoint in there, and narrow down the freeze to its root cause, since I'm at a dead end. If someone can 100% tell me that these two are absolutely identical, perhaps I can assume it's a strange corner-case bug in .NET. Otherwise, I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: @Smashery: Pretty sure it's not a bug in .NET. Something else fishy is going on in your code. It freezes without ever throwing an exception? I would turn on .NET Framework Source Stepping so you can go into the base class and see what's happening. That's in the Debug menu under Options.

Comment: I don't see it (VS2008) - is that a VS2010 thing?

Comment: @Smashery: Possibly. The long way is Tools -> Options -> Debugging. See [this blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx) for a better step-by-step.

Comment: "If the events are members of objects that will stay alive, they will ... prevent them from being properly dispose".  I don't think this is right.  They may prevent them from being garbage collected, but should not affect disposal (releasing unmanaged resources).

Comment: @Joe: Generally, yes. The control will still be disposed and only GC is affected. But event handlers present a tricky situation. Event handlers that aren't removed *can* case problems with disposing the control, and you can start to get some really bad memory leaks. I've seen problems with this before, and there are documented reports of it on the web. It's really not worth worrying about though until it becomes a visible problem with your application. It's quite unusual that event handlers are hooked up to objects that have a longer lifespan than the parent object.

Answer (score 2):

The two are not identical, as you can easily see by looking at the implementation of `Control.Dispose` using Reflector (easy to do while it's still free!)

For example, if you just call Dispose on your panel, it will call DisposeAxControls on each child control, and remove itself from its parent, before calling Dispose on its children.

Nevertheless I agree with Cody Gray - you need to work out why it's freezing rather than trying to "sweep the problem under the carpet" with your proposed workaround.

Normally you don't call Dispose on a Panel explicitly - if you are doing so, you need to be sure you're managing the lifetime and ownership of your controls correctly.

The thing to do is to start simplifying your app step by step until it no longer freezes - to work out what is causing the freeze (for example, by removing the Timers you mentioned one by one - that sounds suspect).  Once you have a very simple example that exhibits the problem it will be easier for you (or someone here) to work out what's going on.