# How can I send other object types from a function to another function using EventHandler

Tags: c#

I would like to make an app that is using INI file to store new FlowLayoutPanels, what I cant get to work on is that I want to make an EventHandler when I DoubleClik a PictureBox that is inside that new FlowLayoutPanel created to delete that very own FlowLayoutPanel.Here is some code:

```
    private void Function(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         FlowLayoutPanel flP = new FlowLayoutPanel();
         PictureBox picB = new PictureBox();
         Label laB = new Label();
         flP.Controls.Add(picB);
         flP.Controls.Add(laB);
         flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(flP);
         picB.DoubleClick += picB_DoubleClick;
    }

    private void picB_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FlowLayoutPanel flp = (FlowLayoutPanel)sender;
        flp.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: What issues are you having exactly? You can pass objects into functions.

Comment: If i run that when i try to dispose that FlowLayoutPanel i get an error saying "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving that error because the `object sender` parameter of the click event is actually the picturebox object. You are trying to act the picturebox as a flow layout panel. You can't do that. A flowlayoutpanel is not a picturebox object and does not inherit from picturebox.

What your probably trying to do can be accomplished by casting sender as a picturebox: `var pb = (picturebox) sender;` and then getting the parent of the picturebox  `var flp = pb.parent as flowlayoutpanel;` and then disposing flp. `flp.dispose();`

I'm typing this answering on my iPhone without access to VS, I'm unsure the consequences of disposing the parent object  from an event of a child object.

Comment: This worked, thanks for the answer. i Have a couple of things i need to get fix, i will post them here later.

Comment: @CodyGray If you dispose the parent, the children won't be garbage collected?

Comment: @CodyGray okay, yes I did mix those two separate concepts. But even still disposing the parent should dispose the children as well. It will dispose itself first and then the children. Because the picturebox click event is not the scope of both the tablelayoutpanel and the picturebox I think everything *should* work out fine? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4894618/3653277

Comment: Haha, well, one cannot remember everything that he once knew! You're right, disposing the parent should be sufficient then.